# Pandas DataFrame to GeoDataFrame with Polygon geometry using groupby and lambda

Tags: python, geopandas, pandas, geodataframe

I have a pandas `DataFrame` like this

```
name    loc_x    loc_y    grp_name
a1        1.0        2.0    set1
a2        2.0        3.0    set1
a3        3.2        4.1    set2
a4        7.9        4.2    set2
```

I want to generate a `GeoDataFrame` that generates a `polygon` using `loc_x` and `loc_y` grouped on `grp_name` and also includes a column `name` that has the values in my original data frame concatenated by `|`? The result should look like this

```
        name    geometry
set1    a1|a2   POLYGON ((1.0, 2.0)...)
set2    a3|a4   POLYGON ((3.2, 4.1)...)
```

I do this to get the geometry column but how do I also get an additional column with `name` concatenated from my base data frame?

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=df.groupby('grp_name').apply(
      lambda g: Polygon(gpd.points_from_xy(g['loc_x'], g['loc_y']))))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using `apply` this can be done using the `agg` method with [named aggregations](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html?highlight=named#named-aggregation). The only thing is that `agg` cannot yet operate on multiple columns, so the points must be condensed to a single column beforehand.

Also note that when converting points to polygons, the aggregation function must call `.values`, since `x` being passed there is a `pd.Series`, which `Polygon` does not know how to handle.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon


df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6'],
                   'loc_x':[0,1,2,3,4,5],
                   'loc_y':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                   'grp_name':['set1','set1','set1','set2','set2','set2']})

df['points'] = gpd.points_from_xy(df.loc_x, df.loc_y)

df = df.groupby('grp_name').agg(
     name     = pd.NamedAgg(column='name',   aggfunc = lambda x: '|'.join(x)),
     geometry = pd.NamedAgg(column='points', aggfunc = lambda x: Polygon(x.values))
    ).reset_index()

geodf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='geometry')

print(geodf)
  grp_name      name                                           geometry
0     set1  a1|a2|a3  POLYGON ((0.00000 1.00000, 1.00000 2.00000, 2....
1     set2  a4|a5|a6  POLYGON ((3.00000 4.00000, 4.00000 5.00000, 5....
```